# Insert copy of a row multiple times with 1 column changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table

```
+---------------------+
| ID | Code | Amount  |
+---------------------+
| 1  | 101  | 1.2     | 
| 2  | 101  | 1.3     |
| 3  | 101  | 1.3     |
| 4  | 101  | 1.4     |
| 5  | 101  | 1.2     |
| 6  | 101  | 1.5     |
| 7  | 101  | 1.4     |
| 8  | 101  | 1.3     |
| 9  | 101  | 1.1     |
| 10 | 101  | 1.0     |
+---------------------+
```

I am trying to copy each row with a unique ID around 20 times and changing

So my output should be like this.

```
+---------------------+
| ID | Code | Amount -|
+---------------------+
| 1  | 101  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 102  | 1.2     | 
| 1  | 103  | 1.2     | 
| 1  | 104  | 1.2     |  
| 1  | 105  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 106  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 107  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 108  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 109  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 110  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 115  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 118  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 121  | 1.2     |
| 1  | 119  | 1.2     | 
| 2  | 101  | 1.3     | 
| 2  | 102  | 1.3     | 
| 2  | 103  | 1.3     | 
| 2  | 104  | 1.3     | 
+---------------------+
```

And so on for the table. The codes are going to be the same for each ID. They are not in an order like my example table above so I will need to hard code them in somewhere. There is 20 more codes I need to add for each ID. The amount will be the same. The ID will be the same. But the code is always going to be different.

I need to update this table to reflect this.

I am having trouble doing it. I can copy the row once. And then change the code. But I can only do that for the first ID and I cannot do any more. Help is very much apreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: "I am having trouble doing it." - any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple 1-column table with the additional codes.

```
CREATE TABLE AdditionalCodes (Code int)

INSERT INTO AdditionalCodes VALUES (102), (103), (104), (105)
```

Now all you have to do is join this table with the original table, and insert the result.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Code, Amount)
SELECT t.ID, c.Code, t.Amount
FROM MyTable t, AdditionalCodes c
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. I already have the codes I need in a table for something else. Just couldn't get my head right today to figure this part out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE or subquery to define the codes.  Here is a method using `VALUES()`:

```
select t.id, c.code, t.amount
from thetable t cross join
     (values(101), (102), (103), . . . ) codes(code);
```